# Angular 4 Resolve manually or update data

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am using the Angular 4 router with resolver.

My example is pretty simple, I have one project `/projects/:id` and then some children :

- `/projects/:id/info`
- `/projects/:id/edit`
- `/projects/:id/rooms`

When using the resolver I just have to get my project from the children like this:

```
(<ActivatedRoute>this.route).parent.data.subscribe((data) => { 
    this.project = data.project 
});
```

But when I edit my project, adding or removing rooms for example, there it is not updated. So I need to find a way to call the resolver manually or update the datas. For now I am doing a `window.location.reload();`  and it is not really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you resolve data just emit an observable ("hot observable" as value) instead of directly emit the value.